# Create three inline blocks and freely place elements inside them without affecting other blocks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create three blocks with set height and width, aligned on top/bottom and also place couple elements inside them. My problem is that anytime I place additional DIVs into one of the elements are number of DIVs inside of each three elements is not the same, it will display the element with "missing" element 1 line lower. See code example below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-inline-block border border-primary" style="width:16%;height:15vh;">
        <div>thing1</div>
        <div>XXX</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-inline-block border border-success" style="width:16%;height:15vh;">
        <div>thing2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-inline-block border border-primary" style="width:16%;height:15vh;">
        <div>thing3</div>
        <div>XXX</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using Bootstrap 5.0. Above code when rendered will show "thing2" box not aligned with other boxes, pushed lower.

Any ideas for this behaviour?

I've tried to wrap elements in additional div to set max height etc, I've played with position-relative/absolute, but I simply don't understand that effect of one box on another.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/vertical-align/

Comment: are you trying to align things1, things2 and things3 in a line?, if yes  then @sweta answered it in a very neat manner, follow that practice

Answer (score 0):

If you are keeping using `display: inline-block`, add `vertical-align: top`

Here's the example snippte:

```css
.d-inline-block {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="d-inline-block border border-primary" style="width:16%;height:15vh;">
            <div>thing1</div>
            <div>XXX</div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline-block border border-success" style="width:16%;height:15vh;">
            <div>thing2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline-block border border-primary" style="width:16%;height:15vh;">
            <div>thing3</div>
            <div>XXX</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

The issue is occurring due to 'd-inline-block'. The solution is to use the grid system, the below code helps:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="block border border-primary">
        <div>thing1</div>
        <div>XXX</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="block border border-success">
        <div>thing2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="block border border-primary">
        <div>thing3</div>
        <div>XXX</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .block {
    height: 15vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Grid system is quite ok, but I find it limiting ability to set fix height and width of each boxes. Shouldn't inline-block allow to put three boxes next to each other? What surprised me is that content of one inline-block DIV has an effect on next box, which does not make it logical to me.

Comment: @bracko - Yes of course inline-block allows that. Check CBroe's comment. All you need is to add "align-top".